# Function called from a react custom hook returns 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I try and call a function from my custom hook I get back an error when the screen loads saying 'handleLazyLoad' is not a function. Im not sure why React cant figure out that the handleLazyLoad is a function, I am thinking I am possible exporting it or calling it incorrectly.

Custom hook:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const useLoadInvoices = (initialPageValue, totalInvoices) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(initialPageValue);

  const pageSize = 30;

  const handleLazyLoad = () => {
    if (currentPage * pageSize < totalInvoices) setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  };

  const totalShownInvoices = currentPage * pageSize > totalInvoices ? totalInvoices : currentPage * pageSize;

  return [totalShownInvoices, handleLazyLoad];
};

export default useLoadInvoices;
```

Invoice Screen Component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import useLazyLoad from './hooks/useLazyLoad';

const InvoicesScreen = () => {
  const [invoices, setInvoices] = useState(null);
  const [totalInvoices, setTotalInvoices] = useState(null);
  const [handleLazyLoad, totalShownInvoices] = useLoadInvoices(1, totalInvoices);

  handleLazyLoad();

  return (
    <AccountPageList
      type="invoices"
      handleLazyLoad={() => handleLazyLoad()}
      start={1}
      finish={totalShownInvoices}
      total={totalInvoices}
      items={invoices}
    />
  );
};

export default InvoicesScreen;
```

Comment: Typo: You got the order of the two elements in your array reversed.

Comment: off topic: `handleLazyLoad={handleLazyLoad}` is better

Comment: Nice one, I didn't realise the order mattered or think of switching it

Comment: is does when its an array, if you had of returned an object, it wouldnt

Comment: @Thomas, depends, sometimes you dont want the args to passed through to the function automatically

Comment: @andymccullough true, but here it doesn't matter. So not having that additional (useless) function is better.

Comment: yep agreed, just wanted to point it out as some dont realise there is a case for both wrapping in another function and not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning an Array from your custom hook, so when destructuring the custom hook the order matters. To Avoid such problems you can change this part in your custom hook from:

```
return [totalShownInvoices, handleLazyLoad];
```

to:

```
return {totalShownInvoices, handleLazyLoad};
```

Then you can destructure it as follows and the order wouldnt matter:

```
const {handleLazyLoad, totalShownInvoices} = useLoadInvoices(
    1,
    totalInvoices,
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The order matters when you destructure on array
Try

```
const [totalShownInvoices,handleLazyLoad] = useLoadInvoices(
    1,
    totalInvoices,
  );
```